# CSOM login : Error validating credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, csom

Good day,

I'm using modern authentication with CSOM for .NET Standard.
I have followed every step described :

- Registered my app on Entra
- I have an Application ID
- Gave the application Sharepoint.AllSites.FullControl
- Granted Admin Consent
- Allowed Public client flows

When I run the code, it says :
var token = Object : "{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.\r\nTrace ID:

I'm 100% sure the username and pass are correct.

```
Uri SPURL = new Uri(settings.SP_URL);
string SPUserName = settings.SP_UserName;
string SPPassword = Tools.DecryptText(settings.SP_Pass);
SecureString secureSPPassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in SPPassword) secureSPPassword.AppendChar(c);

// Note: The PnP Sites Core AuthenticationManager class also supports this  
using (var authenticationManager = new AuthenticationManager())
using (var context = authenticationManager.GetContext(SPURL, SPUserName, secureSPPassword))
{
    context.Load(context.Web, p => p.Title);
    await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Title: {context.Web.Title}");
    return context.Web.Title;
}
```

```
var clientId = defaultAADAppId;
var body = $"resource={resource}&client_id={clientId}&grant_type=password&username={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username)}&password={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password)}";
using (var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
{

    var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, stringContent).ContinueWith((response) =>
    {
        return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var tokenResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(result);
    var token = tokenResult.GetProperty("access_token").GetString();
    return token;
}
```

What am I missing ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the site is MFA-enabled. An MFA-enabled account cannot run in background and it requires interactive login, so if you are trying to do this you need to use a service account that does not have MFA enabled.
Take following steps to disable MFA

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-we-disable-multi-factor-authentication-to/703fffbd-b8d4-4ffd-a8db-c053282265ff